# Docker on Win 10 missing drivers and Sj variable

Tags: docker, build, windows-10, containers

Yesterday everything worked fine. Today I found out that all my local docker containers are gone. Dont know why. So I try to make new containers build via command

```
docker-compose -f C:\wamp64\www\simplaq-api\docker-compose.development.yml build
```

but I am getting this errors:

```
λ docker-compose -f C:\wamp64\www\simplaq-api\docker-compose.development.yml build
time="2023-07-11T09:50:49+02:00" level=warning msg="The \"Sj\" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string."
time="2023-07-11T09:50:49+02:00" level=warning msg="The \"Sj\" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string."
time="2023-07-11T09:50:49+02:00" level=warning msg="The \"Sj\" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string."
[+] Building 0.0s (0/0)
no valid drivers found: Error response from daemon: dial unix /run/guest-services/docker.sock: connect: connection refused
```

Or if I run example from docker

```
λ docker run -d -p 80:80 docker/getting-started
```

I am getting this error:

```
docker: Error response from daemon: dial unix /run/guest-services/docker.sock: connect: connection refused.
```

Does anybody know what is going on there? I have no idea what is going on.

Comment: restart docker service.

Comment: Thank you. Alhtough after docker service restart nothing happened, after computer restart all data are back.

Comment: Make an answer with restart service and computer.

Comment: The issue is that the Docker daemon has crashed, so you need to restart Docker or reboot the system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alhtough after docker service restart nothing happened, after computer restart all data are back. This question helped me second time. Hope somenone else will have the same problem ans find solution here.